# remove all slashes regex

Tags: php, regex, replace

I have string `"h///e/ll\\o\//\"`. 
Need to remove all slashes from it back and forth slashes multiple times can someone show me regex to do this?

its for php preg_replace();

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
var_dump(preg_replace("@[/\\\]@", "", "h///e/ll\\o\\//\\"));
// Output: string(5) "hello"
```

http://codepad.org/PIjKsc9F

Or alternativly

```
var_dump(str_replace(array('\\', '/'), '', 'h///e/ll\\o\\//\\'));
// Output: string(5) "hello"
```

http://codepad.org/0d5j9Mmm

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a regex to remove these:

```
$string = str_replace(array('/', '\\'), '', $string);
```